# Ruby Regexp group matching, assign variables on 1 line

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching

I'm currently trying to rexp a string into multiple variables. Example string:

```
ryan_string = "RyanOnRails: This is a test"
```

I've matched it with this regexp, with 3 groups:

```
ryan_group = ryan_string.scan(/(^.*)(:)(.*)/i)
```

Now to access each group I have to do something like this:

```
ryan_group[0][0] (first group) RyanOnRails
ryan_group[0][1] (second group) :
ryan_group[0][2] (third group) This is a test
```

This seems pretty ridiculous and it feels like I'm doing something wrong. I would be expect to be able to do something like this:

```
g1, g2, g3 = ryan_string.scan(/(^.*)(:)(.*)/i)
```

Is this possible? Or is there a better way than how I'm doing it?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You don't want `scan` for this, as it makes little sense. You can use `String#match` which will return a `MatchData` object, you can then call `#captures` to return an Array of captures. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

string = "RyanOnRails: This is a test"
one, two, three = string.match(/(^.*)(:)(.*)/i).captures

p one   #=> "RyanOnRails"
p two   #=> ":"
p three #=> " This is a test"
```

Be aware that if no match is found, `String#match` will return nil, so something like this might work better:

```
if match = string.match(/(^.*)(:)(.*)/i)
  one, two, three = match.captures
end
```

Although `scan` does make little sense for this. It does still do the job, you just need to flatten the returned Array first. `one, two, three = string.scan(/(^.*)(:)(.*)/i).flatten`

Comment: Beware that if no matches are found, match returns nil and you get a NilError.

If you are in Rails, I suggest you to change:

    `one, two, three = string.match(/(^.*)(:)(.*)/i).captures`

into:

    `one, two, three = string.match(/(^.*)(:)(.*)/i).try(:captures)`

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti I've edited my post, I'm not adding Rails-specific code to it so I have altered it with a version for handling the returned nil object

Comment: You could also the new `&.` operator to get it back on a line and even using it twice when there is only one capture group.  Eg.., `string.match(regex)&.captures&.first`

Answer (score 49):

You could use [Match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-match) or =~ instead which would give you a single match and you could either access the match data the same way or just use the special match variables $1, $2, $3

Something like:

```
if ryan_string =~ /(^.*)(:)(.*)/i
   first = $1
   third = $3
end
```

Comment: @Gaston that's actually the original regexp syntax originating from Perl :)

Answer (score 35):

You can name your captured matches

```
string = "RyanOnRails: This is a test"
/(?<one>^.*)(?<two>:)(?<three>.*)/i =~ string
puts one, two, three
```

It doesn't work if you reverse the order of string and the regex.

Answer (score 7):

You have to decide whether it is a good idea, but ruby regexp can (automagically) *define local variables* for you!

I am not yet sure whether this feature is awesome or just totally crazy, but your regex can define local variables.

```
ryan_string = "RyanOnRails: This is a test"
/^(?<webframework>.*)(?<colon>:)(?<rest>)/ =~ ryan_string
# This defined three variables for you. Crazy, but true.
webframework # => "RyanOnRails"
puts "W: #{webframework} , C: #{colon}, R: #{rest}"
```

(Take a look at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html , search for "local variable").

**Note:**
As pointed out in a comment, I see that there is a similar and earlier answer to this question by @toonsend (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21412455). I do not think I was "stealing", but if you want to be fair with praises and honor the first answer, feel free :) I hope no animals were harmed.

Comment: This answer looks remarkably similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/21412455/525478, which is over a year older...

Comment: @BradWerth I guess I just did not see that. But I updated my answer to include your concerns.

Answer (score 6):

`scan()` will find all non-overlapping matches of the regex in your string, so instead of returning an array of your groups like you seem to be expecting, it is returning an array of arrays.

You are probably better off using `match()`, and then getting the array of captures using `MatchData#captures`:

```
g1, g2, g3 = ryan_string.match(/(^.*)(:)(.*)/i).captures
```

However you could also do this with `scan()` if you wanted to:

```
g1, g2, g3 = ryan_string.scan(/(^.*)(:)(.*)/i)[0]
```