# Ruby Regex for specific format alphanumerics separated by comma

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to validate that the text input in my rails form has contains one or more alphanumerics with specific format separated by comma.

For example the alphanumeric should be either `two letters + seven numbers + one letter + one number` or `two letters + 11 numbers + one letter + one number` . And these alphanumerics must be separated by comma (,)

```
US6174724B1 , US20010002490A1 (This is a valid one)

ruby , rails (This is an invalid one)
```

How can I build a ruby regular expression that checks if (these alphanumerics have specific format) AND if (they are separated by comma)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

**PATTERN**

```
/^(?:(?:^| , )([A-Z]{2}(?:\d{7}|\d{11})[A-Z]\d)\b)+?$/
```

And you will have your alphanumerics in specific format in capture **group 1**.

**INPUT**

> US6174724B1 , US20010002490A1 (This is a valid one)
>
> ruby , rails (This is an invalid one)

**OUTPUT**

```
Match 1: US6174724B1 
Group 1: US6174724B1

Match 2:  , US20010002490A1 
Group 1: US20010002490A1
```

Comment: It works :) . Two questions only , 1) I had to add a forward slash in the beginning and in the end of the regex because otherwise I had an error when I tried to load my page. Why is that ?

2. What do you mean that the alphanumerics will be available in capture group 1 ?

Comment: @Stefanos it depends on the language, usually you should add slash at the beginning and at the end of the pattern just as you did : ) My 'native' language is C# which doesn't require me to do this, anyway added them to the answer as you are using ruby : )

Comment: nice :) , and what do you mean that the alphanumerics will be available in capture group 1 ?

Comment: @Stefanos I'm not sure how about ruby but usually using regex you can **capture certain groups** within **one match**, well sounds bit complicated huh? The capture group is inside parenthesis **( )**, so it will be possible to access certain group via code without including unnecessary things.  Maybe this link will explain it better and more briefly [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) also I have found this question in ruby about capture groups [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303984/ruby-regexp-group-matching-assign-variables-on-1-line)

Comment: Ok , I think I understood how it works. Btw I noticed that the above regex thinks this as valid : US6174724B1invalid whereas it is not since it contains more characters in the end ...

Comment: @Stefanos yeah true, modified it by adding **\b** (word boundry) at the end : ) you can also use **\s** (whitespace) instead and it should work properly as well. I'm telling you this as **\b** sometimes has poor implementation in some languages.

Comment: :well I think that there is one last thing missing and then it will be completely fine : If I have this one " US6174724B1invalid , US20010002490A1 " Then the regex says that this is correct although it is not because the first alphanumeric is not correct. Is it possible to capture this ??

Comment: @Stefanos Ok added the string boundries at the beginning and at the end of the pattern, it should work as intented now.