# ruby regex - how to match everything up until specific html tag

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to extract from a string which looks like this

```
Something<p class=text>Description</p>Something
```

just a "Description". I've tried this `p class=text>[^<\/p]*` and this `p class=text>[^<]\/p*` but none of that is working. How to achieve that ?

Comment: Maybe `<p\s+class=text>[^<]*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to match the entire `class="text"`:

```
<p.*?>(.*?)<\/p>
```

The match group is the tag content. It's simply a lazy quantifier so it doesn't capture the next `<` (and what follows after that).

Comment: Thanks ! Could you tell me is there a way to instantly put everything between those two tags into variable ? Something like <p.*?>$description<\/p>

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303984/ruby-regexp-group-matching-assign-variables-on-1-line